# How do we know whether TURN or STUN server got connected?

Tags: node.js, webrtc, stun

For TURN and STUN server I am using http://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/

Wanted to Create diagnostics to know whether STUN or TURN server is connected.

It would be great help if anyone can help me

1) How to implement it on the server

2) How to implement it on the client side (browser)

Answer (score 0):

turnadmin can help you : TURN server is used if there's no other way. Any user logged in your TURN server didn't have any other choice. https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/wiki/turnadmin

On the browser you'll have to parse the candidates obtaines durein the ice candidates search.